# d3.js zooming mouse coordinates

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js

Im using d3.js zoom function to zoom in on an image inside an svg. Im using a mask to reveal an underlying image beneath. If i dont zoom the mask and mouse cursor coordinates match up perfectly. However, when i start to zoom the mouse coordinates are not translating to the zoom level, thus the map reveal is not lining up with the cursor anymore.

here is what im using so far...Im assuming there needs to be some sort of coordinate translation when zooming?

```
  var lightMap = d3.select("#lightMap").call(d3.behavior.zoom().scaleExtent([1, 3]).on("zoom", zoom));
var darkMap = d3.select("#darkMap").call(d3.behavior.zoom().scaleExtent([1, 3]).on("zoom", zoom));


function zoom() {
lightMap.attr("transform", "translate(" + d3.event.translate + ")scale(" + d3.event.scale + ")");
darkMap.attr("transform", "translate(" + d3.event.translate + ")scale(" + d3.event.scale + ")");


}
var svg = d3.select("svg");


svg.on('mousemove', function () {

 var coordinates = [0, 0];
coordinates = d3.mouse(this);
var x = coordinates[0];
var y = coordinates[1];



    primaryCircle.setAttribute("cy", y + 'px');
    primaryCircle.setAttribute("cx", x + 'px');
```

});

Comment: Do you have a fiddle or something somewhere?  At a guess I'd say it's because your mouse zoom happens on one element, but you're updating that element and another one in the zoom handler which will change the mouse position.  It may be worth grouping the elements in a `g` element and applying the zoom handler to that.  If you can put your code up somewhere, we'll be able to take a look more closely.

Answer (score 4):

(I know this is a late answer but I had the same problem and thought I'd share how I fixed it for future people who see this)

**Fix**: Use `coordinates=mouse(lightMap.node())` / `darkMap.node()` instead of `mouse(this)`. Alternatively, and probably more correctly, call the zoom behavior on `svg` and keep using `mouse(this)`.

**Explanation**: You call the mousemove function on `svg`, so `mouse(this)` gets the coordinates within the `svg` element. However you don't apply the zoom behavior to `svg`, so you get wrong coordinates. Call `mouse(_)` on an element that zooms.